# Left callout view stuck in upperleft corner?

Tags: ios, ios8

I have an `MKPinAnnotationView` which I have customized in the `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` method. In the method I have done the following:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *newAnn = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinAnn"];
newAnn.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
```

But this results in the info button being pushed into the top left corner of the call out. I then tried:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *newAnn = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinAnn"];
UIButton *left = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
left.center = CGPointMake(left.center.x + 5, left.center.y - 5);
newAnn.leftCalloutAccessoryView = left;
```

But it does nothing. I'm on iOS 8 btw. I'm not sure if this happens on iOS 7.

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484608/ios-8-mkannotationview-rightcalloutaccessoryview-misaligned