# Can we remove MKAnnotationView's rightCalloutAccessoryView in ios 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

In my `iPhone` app I required to remove `MKAnnotationView`' `rightCalloutAccessoryView` because right now it shows me white color not button that added to it.
So I decided to show only `letCalloutAccessoryview` in whole `calloutView`.

This problem is only in `iOS 8`.I searched for this thing got this link :

[iOS 8 MKAnnotationView rightCalloutAccessoryView misaligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484608/ios-8-mkannotationview-rightcalloutaccessoryview-misaligned)

In this link it shows that with IOS 8 `rightCalloutView` is not working properly. So I decided to remove that.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't want a rightCalloutAccessoryView, what's stopping you from leaving it or setting it to nil?

Comment: If I set it to nil still there is blank white space showing in callout bubble which i want to avoid .